problem related to tutorial of boost::asio daytime.3
I'm learning this example:
tutdaytime3
I try to replace the tcp_server class using lambda, so I change the main function as following:
asio::io_context io;
tcp::acceptor acceptor{ io, tcp::endpoint{ tcp::v4(), 13 } };
std::function<void(void)> start_accept{
  [&]() {
    auto new_connection{ tcp_connection::create(io) };
    acceptor.async_accept(new_connection->socket(), [&](const error_code& ec) {
      if (ec.failed()) {
        // I got "Already open" error here (from ec.message())
      }
      else {
        new_connection->start();
      }
      start_accept();
    });
  }
};
start_accept();
io.run();

Why the error in the comment happen?

You're storing a reference to the local variable new_connection in your lambda

@AlanBirtles Oh, you're right, I change the capture list to [&, new_connection], error gone, thanks!

Can we make this into an answer? This is a Q&A site after all. /cc @AlanBirtles (but you can it yourself, FillLost)

@AlanBirtles I'm... not sure that dup helps. It doesn't even talk about lambdas or reference/value capture there at all. But thanks for not leaving the question "hanging" as unanswered, which was my main point.
